# Yii2 messages: What does @@ mean?

Tags: php, localization, yii2

After calling `./yii message my-message-config.php` I found that some of my translation were surrounded with `@@`. What does that mean?

Example in messages/de_DE/app.php

```
return [
    ...
    'Edit color' => '@@Farbe ändern@@',
    ...
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In short: Such entries represent localizations for obsoleted keys.**

Quite simple: When you run `./yii message` all your application files get scanned. Newly found keys will just be added to the localization files. However, removed keys will be marked with `@@`. So such strings won't be deleted, rather they get marked. Just to make sure translation work (which can be extensive) doesn't get deleted.

If you find such an marked entry in a localization file you will also find other occurences in other localization files for that key as well - if there are any further translations.

Regarding the example: This means the application code does not contain any `Yii::t('app', 'Edit color')`.

Actually, if you use `./yii message` this information is also part of the comment in the generated/updated localization file...

Comment: So it's basically a NIH gettext and preprocessing thing?

Comment: @mario I never used gettext, so I don't know NIH.